# Elasticsearch, Query String, need match string

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, query-string, string-matching

Sorry if this question is duplicated. Because I can't find any solution in my case. And sorry again, because I'm not good at English.

I'm trying to do a query on Elasticsearch using the query string:

```
{
    query_string: {
        fields: ["name^10"],
        query: q
    }
}
```

When I search with the keyword: `coffee` => The data will response. But when I search with the keyword: `coffe` => Nothing responded.

I want to match `coffe` with `coffee` in the the database. How can I do that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Search for `coffe*` instead and you should find what you want

Comment: @Val No, my idea is allowing user search: `coffe` for `coffee`.

Comment: Ok, but you can append an asterisk no matter what when you create the query. The user type `coffe` but you search for `coffe*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you simply add an asterisk `*` behind what the user is typing, like below, and that should achieve what you need:

```
{
    query_string: {
        fields: ["name^10"],
        query: q + "*"
    }
}
```